# Reduce Autogenerated Metadata in Flash SWF?

Tags: metadata, flash

Some coder friends and I have challenged each other to create a working game with the smallest file size possible. I've made my first attempt in Flash with a mere 273 Actionscript bytes and a 15 byte shape, but I'm getting killed on the whopping 600 bytes of metadata on export. Anybody know if there's a way to knock that down?

The reason I mention the challenge is to make sure you know that this is probably the least important question being asked on StackOverflow atm and if someone else needs help feel free to give it to them first. :-)

Cheers!

Comment: Are you using the Flash IDE to publish this swf ? If so, I'm guessing there would be a metadata panel in publish settings. I remember Flash CS3 onwards or similar introduced an XMP panel so you can add details and make your flash files more [seo friendly](http://oreilly.com/flash/excerpts/seo-for-flash/creating-optimized-flash.html). Perhaps there's an option there not to include these

Comment: Found it! Down to 445 bytes now and well in the lead. Cheers, friend!

Comment: Awesome! I can add my comment as an answer so it can be marked as a solution to the community

Answer (score 0):

If using the Flash IDE, there should be an option to remove the metadata.

Flash CS3 and later introduced an XMP panel in Publish Settings which allows the user to add metadata to make the .swf file [easier to scan](http://oreilly.com/flash/excerpts/seo-for-flash/creating-optimized-flash.html) by Google spiders(as a collaboration between Google and Adobe's Flash Player team).

The publish settings should also allow you to remove/not include metadata